# MongoDB find method with variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, find

Trying to search through my mongoDB database using variable names not by specifying the exact search. Is it possible to do this? No matter how i try to format the variable I can't get a successful search. I'm trying to do something like the bottom line below

```
let url3 = 'http://cs544.io/11jgry2';
const ret = await dbTable.find({"shortUrl" : "http://cs544.io/11jgry2"}); //Works
const ret = await dbTable.find({"shortUrl" : url3}); //Doesn't work
```

Answer (score 1):

Use ***$eq*** it Specifies equality condition. The **$eq** operator matches documents where the value of a field equals the specified value.

Check this [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/eq/) for further explanation and examples

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, it should work,

But I suggest having a look into using [$eq](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/eq/) instead.

Here is an example

```
const ret = await dbTable.find( { shortUrl: { $eq: url3 } } );
```